# to resize the window to keep the div in the center using javascript

Tags: javascript

How can I correct my code to keep the div in the center of the window when it is resized:

```js
window.addEventListener("resize",handleResize,false);
 function handleResize(){
  var newwidth = window.innerWidth.value;
  var newheight = window.innerHeight.value;
  window.resizeTo(newwidth , newheight);
 }
```

Comment: Welcome to SO, please take a minute to read this [how-to-ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) guide

Comment: You should use CSS for positioning, see http://css-tricks.com/centering-in-the-unknown/

Answer (score 0):

There is definitely no need for javascript coding for that: e.g. use [auto margins with a parent container that has absolute or relative positioning instead](http://www.vanseodesign.com/css/vertical-centering/).

Answer (score 0):

You actually do not need to use JavaScript to achieve this. It can be done with pure CSS.

If you still want to use JS, you basically just have to get the `window.innerWidth` and `window.innerHeight` and divide them by 2. This will give you a point in the exact center of the window. Then just subtract half of the width from your element and half of the height to offset the `left` and `top` position of the element you want to center. This is necessary, because the positioning is relative to the upper left corner of the document.

When your using a CSS solution with an absolute positioned element make sure that the parent elements position is set to relative.

Here is an example with both, JS and CSS centering.

```js
var centerDiv = document.querySelector('.center-js'),
    showHideBtn = document.querySelector('.show-hide'),
    winW = 0,
    winH = 0;

// this is just the button click handler.
showHideBtn.addEventListener('click', function() {
  if (centerDiv.style.opacity != 0) {
    centerDiv.style.opacity = 0;
    this.textContent = "Hide CSS centering";
  } else {
    centerDiv.style.opacity = 1;
    this.textContent = "Show CSS centering";      
  }
}, false);

// here is the win resize handler;
function windowResize () {
  winW = window.innerWidth;
  winH = window.innerHeight;
  centerDiv.style.top = (winH/2) - (centerDiv.clientHeight/2) + 'px';
  centerDiv.style.left = (winW/2) - (centerDiv.clientWidth/2) + 'px'; 
}

window.addEventListener("resize", windowResize, false);
windowResize();
centerDiv.style.opacity = 1;
```

```css
html {
  position: relative;
  min-height: 100%;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  color: white;
}

div {
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 200px;
  vertical-align: middle;
}

.center-js {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  background: black;
  opacity: 1;
  transition: opacity .5s linear 0s;
  z-index: 1020;
}

.center-css {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  margin-left: -100px;
  margin-top: -100px;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  background: red;
  z-index: 1010;
}
```

```html
<button class="show-hide">Show CSS centering</button>
<div class="center-js">JS centering</div>
<div class="center-css">CSS centering</div>
```